# Properly display Unicode symbols in my string

Tags: iphone

From webservice iam getting string like this. how to remove unicode symbols and display my string properly.

from : "you don\u2019t have to:"

need to convert like - "you don't have to:"

Answer (score 0):

A workaroud may be:

```
NSString *srt=[yourString stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"\u2019" withString:@"'"];
```